# How can I use "mod rewrite" to redirect a folder path to a subdomain, but without a browser redirect?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a file that I want to redirect to a subdomain using mod_rewrite.  For example, I would like to redirect the request for `http://www.mydomain.com/xyz` to the subdomain `xyz.example.com`

I don't want to send a redirect to the browser though (so it doesn't know the page is different).

BTW. `xyz` is a CNAME record, pointing to `www.otherdomain.com.`

Another example, just to clarify. If `http://www.mydomain.com/xyz/something` is entered into the browser, I want Apache to return the contents of `http://xyz.mydomain.com/something`

Answer (score 2):

I *THINK* this will do what you want it to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)$ http://$1.mydomain.com/$2
```

As this stands it will redirect EVERY request that goes to a subfolder so if you links for images or css that are in a sub folder it will also rewrite those, if you want to list only certain things you could use this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(blog|store|other)/(.*?)$ http://$1.mydomain.com/$2
```

This will only redirect mydomain.com/blog/ mydomain.com/store/ and mydomain.com/other/

Comment: Do you also need the proxy [P] flag at the end of the RewriteRule?

Comment: Don't you need to start it with a ^/ ?

Comment: @jcrossley3 - I'm not sure @gahooa - a ^ yes but not a /

Comment: Hi Unkwntech, thanks for help.
"something" is a long PHP query.
I used the first code you proposed,
and it's working half way.
It loads the xyz subdomain content properly, but in the address bar it shows:
xyz.mydomain.com/something (instead of www.mydomain.com/xyz/something)   

 to be continued

Comment: and if i put in the same address bar again:
www.mydomain.com/xyz/something ( and hit enter)
then it loads again properly, and in the address bar it stays (correctly):
www.mydomain.com/xyz/something
After i press refresh button it loads ok, but the address bar changing to xyz.mydomain.com/something

Comment: Remarks.
1. www.otherdomain.com is on different server
2. [P] at the end doesn't work (either distorted display or proxy error)
3. ^/ at the beginning doesn't work

Comment: Message to Gumbo.
Thanks for your reply. Tried your second code (with Options +FollowSymLinks) and it gives an error page not found.
The code is for .htaccess file in root directory.

Answer (score 1):

If both domains are on the same machine and accessible over the filesystem, you should go this way. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) /absolute/path/to/subdomains/$1/$2
```

If this is not the case, you’ll need a proxy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) http://$1.example.com/$2 [P]
```

These examples are inteded for a .htaccess file. If you want to use them in the httpd.conf, prefix the `RewriteRule` patterns with a `/`.

Comment: Always fix the domain name when applying that. This is shown in the example but I wanted to point out that readers should make sure NOT to provide access to any other domains through the proxy; this has been done by excluding / as a character in the regexp and giving proxy access only to subdomains.