# Redirect domain.com/folder to folder.domain.com permanently

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have catch all rules set up and a subdomain working fine.

However it's still possible to get to a part of my site from http://example.com/subdomain rather than http://subdomain.example.com/

How would I force a permanent redirect?

I'm assuming it's something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
# (rule to see if i am inside subdomain folder)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: As for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597390/how-can-i-use-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-a-folder-path-to-a-subdomain-but-without-a

I do not want http://example.com/subdomain/whatever to redirect to http://subdomain.example.com/whatever. it should return 404 error OR redirect to http://subdomain.example.com/

What is the most elegant way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

you would use this line in your main .htaccess for a simple folder 301 "Moved/Permanent" Redirect

```
Redirect 301 /subdomain http://subdomain.example.com
```

[Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect)